# How to fix "No database selected" error while configuring phpmyadmin?

Tags: php, ubuntu, phpmyadmin

I was trying to configure phpmyadmin on my Ubuntu Linux system and I am receiving an error which says:
`An error occurred while installing the database:                                                                      mysql said: ERROR 1046 (3D000) at line 3: No database selected .`

Can someone tell me how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell MySQL which database to use:

```
USE database_name;
```

before you create a table.(In case the database does not exist, you need to create it as):

```
CREATE DATABASE database_name;
```

followed by:

```
USE database_name;
```